# Python and Jira - How to change fields.resolutiondate

Tags: python, jira

In the past in our project was set not correct workflow and field "resolutiondate" and "resolution" was not changed when you resolve the issue. 
Now our admins correct the workflow for Jira project but we have a lot of issues with empty "resolutiondate".

How could I change the filed "resolutiondate" for issue? Or it is impossible?

In jirashell I try do next:

```
issue.update(fields={'resolutiondate': "2017-04-05T12:06:51.000+0300"})
```

but receive an error:

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://sbtatlas.sigma.sbrf.ru/jira/rest/api/2/issue/451990
        text: Field 'resolutiondate' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

Does I have any ability to set this date?

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. You can't do it using Jira API.